# Trying to fill a graph color drawn with a Bezier Path

Tags: ios

I'm trying a UIBezierPath for the first time and am trying to fill a graph I've drawn with a color but without success. This is what I've done within a custom UIView:

```
- (void)calculateGraphSize
{
    self.topY = CGRectGetMinY(self.bounds);
    self.bottomY = CGRectGetMaxY(self.bounds);
    self.minX = CGRectGetMinX(self.bounds);
    self.maxX = CGRectGetMaxX(self.bounds);
}

- (void) drawRect: (CGRect) rect
{
    CGSize cornerRadius = CGSizeMake(10.0f, 10.0f);

    [self calculateGraphSize];

    UIBezierPath *graphBorder = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners cornerRadii:cornerRadius];
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    [graphBorder fill];


    UIBezierPath *barGraph = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    barGraph.lineWidth = 2.0f;

    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(self.minX, self.bottomY);
    [barGraph moveToPoint:point];

    point = CGPointMake(self.minX + 50, self.bottomY - 50);
    [barGraph addLineToPoint:point];

    point = CGPointMake(self.minX + 100, self.bottomY - 75);
    [barGraph addLineToPoint:point];

    point = CGPointMake(self.minX + 200, self.bottomY);
    [barGraph addLineToPoint:point];

    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [[UIColor greenColor] setFill];
    [barGraph closePath];
    [barGraph stroke];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add [`[barGraph fill]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/fill):

```
[[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
[[UIColor greenColor] setFill];
[barGraph closePath];
[barGraph fill];
[barGraph stroke];
```

You probably want to fill and then stroke as I can't remember if the fill will cover up the stroke (I always have to check ha!)

Comment: Doh, need that coffee

Comment: Always the way - smacks you in the face when you see what you missed! :)

Comment: Another possibility is to use CGContextDrawPath which can do the fill and stroke in one call.